# How to remove the PUT and DELETE methods from the Allow header on Tomcat

Tags: security, tomcat, filter

We are required to remove the so called "unsafe" methods from an out of the box Tomcat 8.5.

When we make the following request:

```
OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:12080
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)
```

We get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 18 May 2020 22:56:15 GMT
```

We made a WebFilter with `<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>` and it works for `OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1` and any other OPTIONS but `OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1`.

¿How can we filter (or block) `OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1`?